# How do I check for blank in DataView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

Assuming I have a column called A and I want to check if A is null or blank, what is the proper way to check for this using the DataView's RowFilter:

```
DataTable dt = GetData();

DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

dv.RowFilter = "A IS NOT NULL OR A IS NOT ''";
```

The above doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: isNullOrWhitespace: ``dgv.RowFilter = "YourColumnName Is Null Or Trim(YourColumnName) = ''"``

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you tied to .net < 3.5? If not you can use linq to check the state of a column.

Otherwise there is an `Isnull(,)` function like in T-SQL:

```
dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(a,'') <> ''";
```

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you need to retrieve all the records where the value in column A is neither null nor ''

The correct expr is:

```
 dv.RowFilter = "A IS NOT NULL AND A <> ''";
```

And to retrieve the filtered records loop on dv.ToTable() like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dv.ToTable().Rows)
    Console.WriteLine(dr["A"]);
```

This should work ... cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

You can add

`dv.RowFilter = "CONVERT(Isnull(a,''), System.String) <> ''"`

if a column has data type of number as Isnull(a,'') would return number. Eval of number <> 0 would throw the exception.