# how can I disable rows in my gridview with datasource rowfilter?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, rowfilter

How can I hide rows in my Gridview with a specific value? For example I want to hide all rows with column("dubletten_Vorschlaege") is empty

```
    skmTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.Tables("SKM2").DefaultView.RowFilter = "Dubletten_Vorschlaege =Nothing"
```

said he cant find the column nothing?

```
    skmTabelle.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.Tables("SKM2").DefaultView.RowFilter = "Dubletten_Vorschlaege ="""
```

said he cannot read the statement at """

I've never used rowfilter so I hope someone can explain.

Edit:
thx levi, it doesn't throw an exception now. But the gridview doesn't change. how do I do that? Do I need to use the fill query again?

on the formload event I have

```
Me.SKM2TableAdapter.Fillg(Me.SLXADRIUMDEVDataSet.SKM2, Module1.pkey)
```

which only selects the rows which are new.
for example I imported new 2000 rows it only shows them.
Do I need to use this statement again?

Comment: Well this is just not worth the effort, I just added a new sql statement to the datasource and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to this site for a few tips on using rowfilter. 
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

In your case, I think the proper way may be to write the string like this. I have followed a similar approach and this worked.

```
...DefaultView.RowFilter = "Dubletten_Vorschlaege ='" & "'"
```

you will notice that i add a single quote after the = and again add a single quote within double quotes after the &.

Also, I refer you to this StackOverflow link 
[How do I check for blank in DataView.RowFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883992/how-do-i-check-for-blank-in-dataview-rowfilter)
The user simply added the line of code as this:

```
...DefaultView.RowFilter = "Dubletten_Vorschlaege = ''"
```

notice the two single qoutes before the ending double quote.